# Error: Could not load or find main class language

Tags: java, nlp, mallet

I am new to Mallet

I have installed Mallet in my computer. I have set the class path correctly (I verified it by printing the class path)

I want to execute the following command mallet import-smvlight file1 file2.mallet

Everytime I try running a command I get an error saying "Error: Could not find or load main class Language"

Can somebody please help me out with the same? I am in deep trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

I installed mallet recently. I haven't used the svmlight thing but simple version and typed the command

```
bin/mallet --import-data filename output op.mallet
```

initially this command was giving error `Could not load the main class` - the reason I figured out was the directory where I installed mallet was not `C:/`. I had gone through one post saying that mallet needs to be installed in `C:/` directory, so check this. Once I did this, this error did not come.

regards,