# Java Classpath error (Could not find or load main class) when using Mallet (a text analysis program) from Command Line

Tags: java, load, classpath, mallet, classnotfound

I’m trying to use [Mallet](https://mimno.github.io/Mallet/import) for the textual analysis of medieval English romances. Mallet is coded in Java and runs from the Command Line.

When I import a text file into Mallet with: *bin\mallet import-dir --input sample-data\web\en\Chaucher.text --output tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords*

I get a Java classpath error: *Could not find or load main class Files\Mallet\Mallet-2.0.8\class;C:\Program Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Mallet\Mallet-2/0/8\class;C:\Program*

Suggested solutions found through Google failed. When I posted this question Stack**overflow** automatically referred me to [How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)

Following this, I set the classpath by running *Java -classpath c:\program files\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\sample-data\web\en*. I still got the same error (*Error: Could not find or load main class files\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\sample-data\web\en Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: files\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\sample-data\web\en*) - note, though, being unfamiar with Java I may have misunderstood this post.

I am now lost, unsure if my environment variables and paths are correctly set or if my Command Line Java code is incorrect. I believe I have correctly followed all the installation instructions, including setting environment and paths for Java, Ant and Mallet, as well advice in Stack**overflow** posts.

I would, then, be most grateful for suggestions as to where I might go from here.

**Background**

I am running Windows 10 Professional on a Dell T7910 Workstation with 64 GB of memory.

I have 1) installed: Java, Ant and Mallet as instructed by various Mallet websites.* 2) have modified environment variables as follows:

Java_Home - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2 (This is in System Variables)

Mallet_Home - C:\Program Files\Mallet\Mallet-2.0.8 (This is in System
Variables)

Ant_Home - c:\Program Files\Ant (I have this in *User* Variables rather
than *System* Variables. *Could this be a problem?*)

My Paths are:
%ant_home%\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\Bin
%Mallet_Home%\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

I have successfully installed Mallet, as when I run *bin\mallet*, I get the verifying response, *Mallet 2.0 commands:*

My Mallet directory structure is as follows. The program is installed in: *c:\program files\mallet* This directory has four sub directories.

cc
class
mallet
mallet-2.0.8 (*Mallet-2.0.8 has the following eight(8) sub directories*)

bin
class
dist
lib
sample-data  (which includes: *\web\en\Chaucer.txt*)
src
stoplists
test

with *Chaucer.txt* being the text file I want to load into Mallet (could this be the problem? I have read that “*import-dir is designed to take multiple directories as input*.” ([Trick to use file paths with spaces in Mallet (Terminal, OSx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796435/trick-to-use-file-paths-with-spaces-in-mallet-terminal-osx)).

I am running my Java classpath and Mallet import code from: c:\program files\mallet\mallet-2.0.8.

My thanks in advance for anyone who can advise me how I should set my Java classpaths when using Mallet.

---

- I consulted the following webpages for installing and using Mallet:

https://mimno.github.io/Mallet/import
https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/topic-modeling-and-mallet

Postings I reviewed for answers to my path problem include:

[Running MALLET on Windows; could not find or load main class cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536402/running-mallet-on-windows-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-cc-mallet-classify)
[Using Mallet on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791096/using-mallet-on-cygwin)
[Error: Could not load or find main class language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557629/error-could-not-load-or-find-main-class-language)
[Mallet SimpleTagger Classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219351/mallet-simpletagger-classpath)
[Trick to use file paths with spaces in Mallet (Terminal, OSx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796435/trick-to-use-file-paths-with-spaces-in-mallet-terminal-osx)
[How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: Given the presence of spaces in the path, you need to enclose the value of the classpath parameter in double quotes (i.e. instead of `-classpath c:\program files\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\sample-data\web\en`, you need to use `-classpath "c:\program files\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\sample-data\web\en"`, otherwise the part after the space is considered the classname you're trying to run.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I very much appreciate it. Unfortunately, it did not work. Since my post I have tired very many combinations of environment variables and paths as well as command prompts. None of them have worked. I assume I am having a Java problem. For some reason I cannot fathom, I am unable to specify to Java a/the path(s) to the relevant Mallet sub directories - or at least this i how I understand the problem.  Quite a few Mallet users have had this problem, but were able to overcome.  Their solutions have not worked for me, though. Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: The error shown in your question happens when using `java -classpath C:\program Files\Mallet\Mallet-2.0.8\class;C:\Program files\.... ClassNameToStart` instead of `java -classpath "C:\program Files\Mallet\Mallet-2.0.8\class;C:\Program files\...." ClassNameToStart`. There is nothing more to it. If your application is using a launcher script that doesn't properly handle spaces in paths, then consider installing the program in a path without spaces (i.e. *not* in `C:\Program Files`).

Comment: Tried this before to no avail

Do I need to specify where my Mallet Java jar files are installed?

Reviewed https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-jar-file-to-classpath-in-java/ and ran: java -classpath /classes;"C:\Program Files\Mallet\mallet-2.0.8\lib\*" 

Only to get an explanation of  the Java classpath command.

Any suggestions as to my error?

My assumption now is that I need to set a Java classpath to the subdirectory were my Mallet Java jar files are stored. Do you agree? If so, how would you suggest I do this?

Thanks again, for your suggestion. I much appreciate it.

Comment: You're quoting part of your classpath instead of the classpath itself. That is, you should have used `java -classpath "/classes;C:\Program Files\Mallet\mallet-2.0.8\lib*"` (though that `/classes` looks incorrect to me). I have no idea what mallet is, or how it is installed. Your problem isn't even really a Java problem, but the basic functioning of arguments in command prompts/shells.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, but I solved the problem by uninstalling Java, Ant and Mallet and then reinstalling them.

Problem was probably that I installed Mallet in c:\Program Files\Mallet. When I reinstalled Mallet, I installed it in C:\Mallet.

So far it seems to be working.

Thanks again everyone for your suggestions. I very much appreciate them

Comment: Which is what I suggested earlier (_"[..] then consider installing the program in a path without spaces (i.e. not in `C:\Program Files`)"_)